# Integration by parts, twice

Tags: integration

Use the substition $u=4x-3$ to find $\int\frac{4x}{4x-3}dx$, giving your answer in terms of $x$
$$u=4x-3$$
$$4x=u+3$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=4$$
$$dx=\frac{1}{4}du$$
$$\int\frac{4x}{4x-3}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{4}\int(u+3)\frac{1}{u}du$$
Integration by parts, to avoid confusion I use $a$ and $b$
$$a=u+3$$
$$\frac{da}{du}=1$$
$$\frac{db}{du}=\frac{1}{u}$$
$$b=ln(u)$$
Integration by parts formula
$$\int a\frac{db}{du}du=ab-\int b\frac{da}{du}du$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{4}((u+3)ln(u)-\int ln(u))du$$
Integration by parts, again
$$-\int ln(u)du$$
$$\Rightarrow-\int 1\cdot ln(u)du$$
Again, to avoid confusion I will use $y$ and $z$
$$y=ln(u)$$
$$\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{1}{u}$$
$$\frac{dz}{du}=1$$
$$z=u$$
Integration by parts formula
$$\int y\frac{dz}{du}du=yz-\int z\frac{dy}{du}du$$
$$\Rightarrow u ln(u)-\int \frac{u}{u}du$$
$$\Rightarrow u ln(u)-u$$
Put every together $+c$ and substitute back in $u=4x-3$
$$\frac{1}{4}((u+3)ln(u)-\int ln(u))du$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{4}((u+3)ln(u)-(u ln(u)-u))+c$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{4}((4x)ln(4x-3)-(4x-3)ln(4x-3)+(4x-3))+c$$

The answer according to the Mark scheme is
$$\frac{1}{4}((4x-3)+3ln(4x-3))+c$$

Where did I go wrong, thanks

Comment: oh my gosh, don't complicate it for yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer is correct after some simplifications. But there is a much faster way: rather than integrate by parts, simply write $\frac{u+3}{u}=1+\frac{3}{u}$, then integrate each term separately.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
I&=\int \!4\,{\frac {x}{4\,x-3}}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=4\,\int \!{\frac {x}{4\,x-3}}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=4\,\int \!\bigg\{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\, \frac{1}{\left( 4\,x-3 \right)}\bigg\}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=4\,\int \!\frac{1}{4}\,{\rm d}x+4\,\int \!\frac{3}{4}\, \frac{1}{\left( 4\,x-3 \right)}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=x+4\,\int \!\frac{3}{4}\, \frac{1}{\left( 4\,x-3 \right)}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=x+3\,\int \! \frac{1}{\left( 4\,x-3 \right)}\,{\rm d}x\\
&=x+3\,\int \!\frac{1}{4}\,\frac{1}{u}\,{\rm d}u\\
&=x+\frac{3}{4}\,\int \!\frac{1}{u}\,{\rm d}u\\
&=x+\frac{3}{4}\,\ln  \left( u \right)+C\\
&=x+\frac{3}{4}\,\ln  \left( 4\,x-3 \right)+C 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you have arrived at the correct answer by the long route.   There were easier paths, but you got there in the end.

You had finished with: $$\frac{1}{4}((4x)\ln(4x-3)-(4x-3)\ln(4x-3)+(4x-3))+c 
$$

And just needed to simplify a bit more:

$$\begin{align}
=~&\frac{1}{4}((4x-(4x-3))\ln(4x-3)+(4x-3))+c 
\\[1ex] =~&\frac{1}{4}(3\ln(4x-3)+(4x-3))+c & \text{the mark scheme's answer}
\\[1ex] =~& \frac 34\ln(4x-3)+ x + (c-\frac 3 4)
\\[1ex] =~& x+\frac 34\ln(4x-3) + c_1 & \text{the simplest answer}
\end{align}$$